# Is syncing the photos library database between computers supported?

Tags: file-management, photos

I have the `~/Photos` folder synced between several computers using [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/).

I would also like to sync the Photos (shotwell) application library database, so all of my work organizing and editing the photos can be kept current across computers.

It appears that the default location for the database is `~/.local/share/shotwell/data/photo.db`

Can this be relocated under the `~/Photos` dir? Are there any known issues with database corruption when syncing it between multiple hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Shotwell FAQ](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell/FAQ) does not recommend it:

***Can I access a Shotwell library across a network, possibly from multiple machines?***
This is not recommended. Shotwell was not designed to support this use case, and the database can get into an inconsistent state. See this SQLite page on network access of a database file, in particular the problem of file sharing protocols not properly locking the database which can cause corruption.

*[Ticket #715764](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=715764) tracks progress on making library network synchronization available in the future.*